# How to add explanatory text to powerpoint master slide

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

The default powerpoint master contains explanatory text in the respective text boxes.

Here is an example in german:

[image]

"Click to add title"
"Click to add subtitle"

**Question**: How can I get powerpoint to show such a text for my custom template?

---

Edit: The text "Titel durch Klicken hinzufügen" is only an explanation which will vanish as soon as the text field comes into focus. I don't want to add text which the user of the template has to remove if he does not want the title of the presentation to be "Click to add title".

What happens after selecting the title field:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View | Slide Master
Edit the text in the placeholders of the layouts to say whatever you want them to.

Comment: I don't want to add actual text to the master. Only an explanation. Please see edit.

Comment: If you can't afford the ten seconds it would take to TRY what I suggested before dismissing it, I won't waste any more of your time.

Comment: you are right! ... don't know what I did wrong the first time.

Comment: OK.  I'll waste your time some more.  ;-)